# How to use jQuery to show/hide divs based on radio button selection?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, mouseclick-event

I have some radio buttons and I'd like to have different hidden divs show up based on which radio button is selected. Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<form name="form1" id="my_form" method="post" action="">
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1">opt1</label></div>  
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt2">opt2</label></div>  
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt3">opt3</label></div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

....

<style type="text/css">
    .desc { display: none; }
</style>

....

<div id="opt1" class="desc">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="opt2" class="desc">consectetur adipisicing</div>
<div id="opt3" class="desc">sed do eiusmod tempor</div>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='group2']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
```

The reason I'm doing it that way is because my radio buttons and divs are being generated dynamically (the value of the radio button will always have a corresponding div). The code above works partially - the divs will show when the correct button is checked, but I need to add in some code to make the divs hide again once the button is unchecked. Thanks!

Comment: As @ste-yeu mentioned, please correct the selector to 'group1' in your jQuery :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update 2015/06**

As jQuery has evolved since the question was posted, the recommended approach now is using `$.on`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=group2]").on( "change", function() {

         var test = $(this).val();
         $(".desc").hide();
         $("#"+test).show();
    } );
});
```

or outside `$.ready()`

```
$(document).on( "change", "input[name=group2]", function() { ... } );
```

**Original answer**

You should use `.change()` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name=group2]").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
```

should work

Comment: i added this to input `<?php if($ic==1) {echo "checked"; $ic++;} ?>` so that a default radio buuton is checked it worked but `jquery` doesn't trigger div

Answer (score 39):

Just hide them before showing them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='group2']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name=group1]").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
```

It's correct `input[name=group1]` in this example. However, thanks for the code!

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" />Book</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Non-Book</label>

<div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="display:none">

    <form action="success1.html">

        Name1:<input type="text" name="name">
             <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">

    <form action="success1.html">

        Name2:<input type="text" name="name">
             <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

An interesting solution is to make this declarative: you just give every div that should be shown an attribute `automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked` with the id of the checkbox or radio button on which it depends. That is, your form looks like this:

```
<form name="form1" id="my_form" method="post" action="">
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="rdio1" value="opt1">opt1</label></div>  
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="rdio2" value="opt2">opt2</label></div>  
</form>
....
<div id="opt1" automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked="rdio1">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="opt2" automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked="rdio2">consectetur adipisicing</div>
```

and have some page independent JavaScript that nicely uses functional programming:

```
function executeAutomaticVisibility(name) {
    $("[name="+name+"]:checked").each(function() {
        $("[automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked=" + this.id+"]").show();
    });
    $("[name="+name+"]:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        $("[automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked=" + this.id+"]").hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    triggers = $("[automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked]")
        .map(function(){ return $("#" + $(this).attr("automaticallyVisibleIfIdChecked")).get() })
    $.unique(triggers);
    triggers.each( function() {
        executeAutomaticVisibility(this.name);
        $(this).change( function(){ executeAutomaticVisibility(this.name); } );
    });
});
```

Similarily you could automatically enable / disable form fields with an attribute `automaticallyEnabledIfChecked`.

I think this method is nice since it avoids having to create specific JavaScript for your page - you just insert some attributes that say what should be done.

Answer (score 4):

The simple jquery source for the same -

```
$("input:radio[name='group1']").click(function() {      
    $('.desc').hide();
    $('#' + $("input:radio[name='group1']:checked").val()).show();
});
```

In order to make it little more appropriate just add checked to first option --

```
<div><label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1" checked>opt1</label></div>
```

remove .desc class from styling and modify divs like --

```
<div id="opt1" class="desc">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="opt2" class="desc" style="display: none;">consectetur adipisicing</div>
<div id="opt3" class="desc" style="display: none;">sed do eiusmod tempor</div>
```

it will really look good any-ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery’s `show()` and `hide()` methods. Like below:

**JQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      var val = $(this).attr("value");
      var target = $("." + val);
      $(".msg").not(target).hide();
      $(target).show();
    });
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow"> Yellow
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Red
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> Green

<div class="yellow msg">You have selected Yellow</div>
<div class="red msg">You have selected Red</div>
<div class="green msg">You have selected Green</div>
```

Here is an example: [Show/hide DIV based on Radio Button click](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-show-hide-div-based-on-radio-button-click/)

Answer (score 1):

Below code is perfectly workd for me:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    label{ margin-right: 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code to unterstand you to how to make a show and hide radio buttons in jquery its very simple

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">

    Value Based<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />

    Percent Based<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />
    <br>
    <div id="Cars2" class="desc" style="display: none;">
        <br>
        <label for="txtPassportNumber">Commission Value</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div id="Cars3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
        <br>
        <label for="txtPassportNumber">Commission Percent</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).show();
    });
});
```

give me comments