# jQuery Radio Button Show/Hide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use radio buttons to show and hide a div but can't get the below to work, any help would be great?

```
    $('input:radio[name="option"]').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == "pop" ) {
        $(this).parent().next('.wrapper').show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next('.wrapper').hide();
    }
});

<input name="option" type="radio">
<input name="option" type="radio" value="pop">

<div class="wrapper">text</div>
```

Comment: Please update your HTML to show the parent, and another set of radios and `class="wrapper"` tags. As it is, what you have here isn't enough to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777139 ?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `parent()`, as the `.wrapper` element is at the same level than the input.

You also want `nextAll`, not `next`, because `next` only selects the immediately following sibbling.

Working code :

```
$('input:radio[name="option"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.val() == "pop" ) {
        $this.nextAll('.wrapper').show();
    } else {
        $this.nextAll('.wrapper').hide();
    }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/AwYjY/)

If you want only the first following `.wrapper` element, then you may use this :

```
$('input:radio[name="option"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), $wrapper = $this.nextAll('.wrapper').eq(0);
    if ( $this.val() == "pop" ) {
        $wrapper.show();
    } else {
        $wrapper.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the parent tag as I have this form repeated a few times on the page and I don't want all the wrapper classes to close.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.parent().next('wrapper').` has nothing to grab on to (there is no such element).

This will work

```
$('.wrapper').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input[value='pop']").on("click", function() {
        $(".wrapper").toggle();
    });
});
```