# How to display a specific hidden form in JSP based upon radio button selection?

Tags: jquery, jsp, radio-button

I want to display specific hidden forms in JSP depending upon the radio button selected from multiple radio button options. Is there any specific Jquery for that?

Comment: In the client, there is no JSP, only HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution: Use the selector :checked

```
if ($('input:checked').val() == 'Milk')
```

Check out the working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUmTk/)

Comment: Thanks got it..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777139/how-to-use-jquery-to-show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection -see this post too.