# How to display only two buttons when radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, hidden-field

I have a form that implements 3 buttons. Each button offers a different option for the user to select. The page only renders two of the buttons, the last one is hidden. I want to change the ones that display depending on the radio button input.

**This is the HTML document that I am working with:**

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="pay">Payment Option</label>
          <div class="row check">
            <div class="col-sm-6">          
              <input type="radio" id="gcash" name="pay" value="gcash" checked="checked"/>
              <label for="gcash" class="pay">Gcash</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="radio" id="walk" name="pay" value="unpaid"/>
              <label for="walk" class="pay">Walk In</label>
            </div>
     </div>

    <div class="buttons">
          <a href="#" class="res-btn" role="button">Back</a>
          <a href="#" class="res-btn" role="button">Proceed payment</a>
          <input type="submit" class="res-btn hidden" name="btn-submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
```

Comment: `onchange -> if value is -> show/hide`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jQuery to show/hide divs based on radio button selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777139/how-to-use-jquery-to-show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection)

Comment: Your going to have to implement JavaScript buddy, and dynamically change the hidden CSS class on that last button. "class="res-btn hidden" or you can remove the word hidden if you don't want it hidden at all, but that might cause validation issues for you.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey did not work on me bruh

Answer (score 0):

```js
radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value)
});
```

use this handler for getting data of radio

then, find your element and use

element.classList.toggle("hidden");

for toggle class name, which uses in your css

Comment: how do i toggle it? i have not idea about javascript. hidden classname is display block in my css.

Comment: use your own class name in "toggle()" method. this class should be with "display: none;" property in css

Comment: "how do i toggle it?" 
find your element with element = document.getElementById(id);
and call
element.classList.toggle("your_class");